# Using JQuery Sticky Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to do the classic Sticky Element in reverse.

See http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/ for an example of a typical sticky experience.

What I want to do instead, is to have an element that initially docks flush with the bottom of the users window, and then stops and docks on the footer when he scrolls down that far. Is there a better way to initialize this plugin, or use another to accomplish this?

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/ is probably the updated version of the older link (now that the plugin has been refactored to not rely strictly on jQuery, though the Sticky shortcut/extension does require the jQuery build it seems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [documentation](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), it can be achieved as follows:

```
$('#footer').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $('#footer-content').toggleClass('sticky', direction === 'up');
}, {
   offset: function() {
      return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight();
   }
});
​
```

I assign `.sticky` to `#footer-content` initially (in the html).

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/rJqFj/).

Comment: This works, until I reach the bottom.  Then when I scroll back up the footer doesn't stick anymore.  Perhaps a moot point since the version of the library used in the fiddle is quite old, but a heads up in case anyone else is looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Here's an updated version of the fiddle with the issue fixed (and using the latest version of the library + the Sticky shortcut): http://jsfiddle.net/jinglesthula/68903kzc/

Answer (score 1):

you can change the css to make it flush with the bottom of the screen by setting `bottom : 0px` for the `.top` class selector

currently the item actually is a part of the footer so it would not be an easy functionality to add to make it stop scrolling at a certain point at the page.

i imagine you would have to set a max scroll height variable in the javascript and when you reach that scroll, get the offset of the element, change its position to absolute and set the position to the offset that you saved. if they are below the max scroll height, change position back to fixed.